# How do you get SAM to shut up?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I know it's cold out SAM, you don't have to tell me every time I step away from a solar heater. I know there's resources to be mined, that's why I'm in the area with my display up. I know there is a Remnant camp up ahead, they are currently shooting at us.

Is there any way to stop this AI in my head from telling me these things?!

Comment: His chattiness actually interferes with the game, in that it will drown out or even halt other dialogue.  I've reloaded a save or two just to re-approach a dialogue trigger from a different direction so that SAM won't talk over people.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As an avid SAM hater, I, too, hoped for a "mute SAM" option. Sadly, it does not appear that there is one at this time, though many users have complained and requested one. From [this article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-03-27-mass-effect-andromeda-players-want-mute-for-chatty-ai-sam):

> there's no telling him to stop, and sadly (as yet) no mute button. All players can hope for is that SAM calms down after the game's next big patch.

Comment: RYDER, THIS AREA CAN BE MINED FOR RESOURCES

Comment: "HEY, RYDER, [LISTEN](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KN1WlLVoHSQ/hqdefault.jpg)"

Comment: @xDaizu Such a love hate relationship with Navi. She pissed me off, but I was still sad when she flew away :(

Comment: @Cruncher Spoiler alert!

Comment: @Colin For a 19 year old video game?

Comment: @Colin if they haven't played it by now they never will 

Comment: I DIDN'T KNOW NAVI LEAVES!